# selection rows with special conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe :

```
TIMESTAMP equipmeent1 equipement2 class_energy
    2016-05-10 04:30:00 107 0 high
    2016-05-10 04:40:00 100 90 medium
    2016-05-10 04:50:00 106 0 low
    2016-05-10 05:00:00 107 0 high
```

I  try to select rows with special condition :

```
x.loc[x['class_energy'] == 'high',  x['TIMESTAMP'] > 2016-05-10 04:30:00 04:10:00,x['TIMESTAMP'] < 2016-05-10 05:00:00 ]
```

But I get this problem :

> ```
> IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-241-b47c8396bb9a> in <module>()
> ----> 1 x.loc[x['class_energy'] == 'high', x['PERIODE_TARIF'] =='HP']
>
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py
> ```
>
> in **getitem**(self, key)
>          1292 
>          1293         if type(key) is tuple:
>       -> 1294             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
>          1295         else:
>          1296             return self._getitem_axis(key, axis=0)
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py
> ```
>
> in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
>           802                 continue
>           803 
>       --> 804             retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
>           805 
>           806         return retval
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py
> ```
>
> in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
>          1437             return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
>          1438         elif is_bool_indexer(key):
>       -> 1439             return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)
>          1440         elif is_list_like_indexer(key):
>          1441
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py
> ```
>
> in _getbool_axis(self, key, axis)
>          1301     def _getbool_axis(self, key, axis=0):
>          1302         labels = self.obj._get_axis(axis)
>       -> 1303         key = check_bool_indexer(labels, key)
>          1304         inds, = key.nonzero()
>          1305         try:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py
> ```
>
> in check_bool_indexer(ax, key)
>          1799         mask = com.isnull(result._values)
>          1800         if mask.any():
>       -> 1801             raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series key provided')
>          1802 
>          1803         result = result.astype(bool)._values
>
> ```
> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to and the conditions using `&` and use parentheses:

```
x.loc[(x['class_energy'] == 'high') & (x['TIMESTAMP'] > '2016-05-10 04:30:00') & (x['TIMESTAMP'] < '2016-05-10 05:00:00') ]
```

It's unclear what you're intending by randomly including `04:10:00` in your original code

you must use `&` instead of `and` as we are comparing arrays of values, due to operator precedence the conditions need to be enclosed in parentheses also

What you did was just separate each condition with a `,` which is meaningless here and caused an evaluation error as it treated your args as a tuple

Also your error `x.loc[x['class_energy'] == 'high', x['PERIODE_TARIF'] =='HP']` doesn't match your posted code, if you wanted to use these 2 conditions:

```
x.loc[(x['class_energy'] == 'high') & (x['PERIODE_TARIF'] =='HP')]
```

should work

Comment: Thank you EdChurn, it indicates SyntaxError: invalid token  . Remark that the type of TIMESTAMP is 11232 non-null datetime64[ns]

Comment: sorry you need to enclose the datetime in quotes, try the updated answer

Comment: thank you EdChurn, it works, last questio, is it a way to get only TIMESTAMP and class_energy columns?

Comment: Sorry you mean before or after the filtering? You wan just pass a list of cols of interest to `loc` after the conditions after the comma: `x.loc[(x['class_energy'] == 'high') & (x['TIMESTAMP'] > '2016-05-10 04:30:00') & (x['TIMESTAMP'] < '2016-05-10 05:00:00'), ['TIMESTAMP', 'class_energy'] ]`